# If statement do nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, responsive

I've searched a lot for this issue but nothing is working for me. I would like this :

When on device with a width inferior to 850px, the SnapScroll doesn't load.
Above 850px, snap scroll is used.

SnapScroll() is a jQuery function I load in my index.php, before my javascript file, like this :

```
<script src="./snap-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/app.js"></script>
```

Here is my app.js :

```
if (!(window.innerWidth < 850)){
  $(function(){
    $("section").SnapScroll();
  });
}
```

Currently, SnapScroll() is not loaded, no matter the size of the device.
I tried a if/else statement with an empty if or else block according to the condition. I also created a function whose job is to "do nothing" and then use it in the statement. It hasn't worked either.
The jQuery has been made in a way that makes it obligatory to call SnapScroll in another function.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Just a general comment: your if statement is a bit wonky...instead of `!(window.innerWidth < 850)` just do `window.innerWidth >= 850`.

Comment: Are you talking about https://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/jQuery-Snap-Scrolling-Plugin-For-Single-Page-Website-snapscroll.html
Because there's no `SnapScroll()` function in the vanillia JQuery as far as I know

Comment: No need to over-complicate things.  This *should* work:
if (window.innerWidth > 850){
   console.log('load snapscroll');
}
If not, then there's something else in your code interfering.

Comment: Are you sure the line `$("section")` actually yields any elements? Please post your HTML.

Comment: Like Marthyn said, make sure that you are using correct selector. And, you don't need to put $("section").SnapScroll() inside a function if you want to execute it normally.